# Android Studio Gradle sync failed: Unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: gradle

I am getting this error on Android Studio 3.5.3. I have tried adding the maven repositories, I also tried to add Gradle manually and giving Android Studio the path. But nothing seems to work. I am also attaching a print screen. I have also installed the Keystore explorer "http://keystore-explorer.org/downloads.html". But it seems it's not working.

```
{
repositories {
    jcenter()
    ***maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"}***
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    ***jcenter{ url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }***
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a proper certification to the JDK your android project is using? You can download the certification through google chrome. Below is the solution worked for me.

[image]

1. Click the highlighted button and store the certification as a file.
2. Open Keystore Explorer as administrator.
3. Check JDK Location of your android project.(File > Project Structure > JDK Location)
4. Find security cacerts from the location above.(Generally the path is jre/jre/lib/security/cacerts)
5. In the KeyStore Explorer, open cacerts you find. Add the certification you downloaded to the cacerts.
6. Save and restart the Android Studio!